# Como pegar a Id variável de um form em ajax

Tags: php, ajax, script

Eu preciso saber como enviar a id do formulário, que varia de acordo com a ID do post, que seria algo do tipo myForm'.$id.' para poder tratar cada form em si.
O formulário é enviado através do script:

```
function rpbox(value, valor) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"+value).keydown(function(evt) {

            var message = $("#"+value).val();

            if (evt.keyCode == 13 && !evt.shiftKey) {        

                if (message != ''){
                    if (document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display == "none") {
                        document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display = "table";
                        document.getElementById("l"+valor).style.display = "none";
                    }
                    $("#myForm"+valor).submit();

                }
                $("textarea").val('');
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
         });
    });
}
```

Esse script seria para tratar o formulário que eu preciso tratar o IDdoform.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#"+IDdoform).ajaxForm({
        target: ".comment_all",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(){
            $(".comment_all").append;
        }
    }); 

});
```

Outra questão é que tenho um "botão" que mostra a quantidade de comentários existentes, porém quando adiciono pelo ajax, o botão fica com a quantidade anterior. Não faço ideia se tem como atualizar ele.

```
<input class="lsubmit4" type="button" name="'.$post['id_p'].'" value="Comment ('.$rows.')" onclick="openReply(this.name)"/>
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

   function rpbox(value, valor) {
        $("#"+value).keydown(function(evt) {
            var message = $("#"+value).val();
            if (evt.keyCode == 13 && !evt.shiftKey) {        

                if (message != ''){
                    if (document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display == "none") {
                        document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display = "table";
                        document.getElementById("l"+valor).style.display = "none";
                    }
                    $("#myForm"+valor).trigger("submit", valor);

                }
                $("textarea").val('');
            }
         });
   }

   $(".imagem_news").click(function(){
      var id = this.id;
      var valor = this.id.match(/\d+/);
      rpbox(id, valor);
   });

   $("form").submit(function(e, i){
    var myForm = "myForm"+i;
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#"+myForm).ajaxForm({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'processing.php',
   target: '.comment_all',
   success: function(){
    $(".comment_all").append;
           }
       }); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Já tentou enviar pelo `data: { idform: IDdoform}`?

Comment: No caso do botão, como ele é enviado pelo PHP, creio que vc deve pegar o valor atualizado após fazer uma consulta ao banco pegando a quantidade e somando +1, se foi isso que entendi.

Comment: @Sam o data eu teria que usar dentro do ajaxForm, não? Eu preciso receber esse IDdoform antes de chamar o ajax. O id do formulário normalmente é myForm'.$post['id'].'.

Comment: Entendi. Nesse `$("#"+IDdoform).ajaxForm({` vc precisa que a variável `IDdoform` seja a ID do formulário.

Comment: Como é chamada essa função `rpbox`?

Comment: @Sam `<textarea name="editor1" id="text'.$post['id_p'].'" onclick="rpbox(this.id, '.$post['id_p'].')" class="imagem_news" placeholder="Your Comment..." ></textarea>`

Comment: @Sam então, sobre o botão, existe alguma forma de atualizar ele sem atualizar a página?

Comment: Pode atualizar o botão via Ajax pelo name: `$("[name="+ID+"]").val("Comment ("+VALOR RETORNADO DO AJAX+")")`

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tem alguns problemas e coisas meio sem sentido, como por exemplo um `$(document).ready(function() {` dentro da função(?). Esse `evt.preventDefault();` e `return false;` não têm razão de ser também.

O que você deve fazer é criar um evento `submit` para pegar o envio do formulário e enviar a sua `id` através de um parâmetro no `trigger submit`. Também não precisa usar `onclick` para chamar a função `rpbox`. Crie um evento `click` para isso, assim você pode colocar todo o código no escopo do `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Seu código todo ficará assim:

**Textarea sem onclick**

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="text'.$post['id_p'].'" class="imagem_news" placeholder="Your Comment..." ></textarea>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

   function rpbox(value, valor) {
        $("#"+value).keydown(function(evt) {

            var message = $("#"+value).val();

            if (evt.keyCode == 13 && !evt.shiftKey) {        

                if (message != ''){
                    if (document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display == "none") {
                        document.getElementById("reply_box"+valor).style.display = "table";
                        document.getElementById("l"+valor).style.display = "none";
                    }
                    $("#myForm"+valor).trigger("submit", valor);

                }
                $("textarea").val('');
            }
         });
   }

   $(".imagem_news").click(function(){
      var id = this.id;
      var valor = this.id.match(/\d+/);
      rpbox(id, valor);
   });

   $("form").submit(function(e, i){
      e.preventDefault();

       $("#myForm"+i).ajaxForm({
           target: ".comment_all",
           type: "POST",
           success: function(){
               $(".comment_all").append;
           }
       }); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Eu fiz algumas modificações pra atender o que eu preciso, mas o que acontece é que quando digito  algo, ele pula uma linha e apaga o que foi escrito e não vai para a página de processamento.

Vou editar no post a modificação que eu fiz.

Comment: Tenho tentado fazer funcionar, e o mais perto que cheguei foi com o ajaxSubmit, mas dai insere os dados 2x. Mas de qualquer forma, o form vai para a página processing.php e não retorna para o post.

Outra coisa é a função append, ela apaga os outros comentários :s

E sem querer, editei sua resposta, desculpe :/